# Get the sum which is greater than 0 or less than 0 using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL query that will get the sum of the amount in my column. What I found out is that there are also negative values in my data. I want to separate the sum of positive values and negative values. Can you help me on this?

I tried this query... but its giving me a **Invalid use of group function**.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 and sum(AMOUNT) > 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution which was posted by someone earlier but unfortunately he deleted it(i dont know why)   Thanks to that person. :)

I tried to consider the Having clause but its giving me a wrong result.

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN AMOUNT > 0 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as Positive, 
sum(CASE WHEN AMOUNT < 0 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as Negative from deposit where type = 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a condition on an aggregate, use `having`:

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 having sum(AMOUNT) > 0
```

Or if you are only interested in summing the positive values, then don't put the condition on the sum, but on the individual amount:

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 and amount > 0
```

Comment: I tried to use the having clause but its not giving me the my expected result. :( 
its giving the Sum of my amount which includes the negative values...
I want to separate the sum of my positive and negative values...

Comment: Then why you have a condition on the sum? Just put the condition on the amount

Answer (score 1):

Use having

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 and amount > 0 having sum(AMOUNT) > 0
```

Comment: I tried to use the having clause but its not giving me the my expected result. :( 
its giving the Sum of my amount which includes the negative values...
I want to separate the sum of my positive and negative values...

Comment: SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 and amount > 0


SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 and amount < 0

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subselect:

```
SELECT s FROM (
   SELECT SUM(amount) s FROM deposit WHERE type = 42
) R
WHERE s > 0;
```

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of situation we have aggregate functions **having** in mysql.

1) If you want to get greater than zero;

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 having sum(AMOUNT) > 0
```

2) If you want to get less than zero;

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) from deposit where type = 42 having sum(AMOUNT) < 0
```

If you want both in one result you can use **subquery**.